# Looping over multiple iframes does not allow html elements to be accessed

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension, runtime-error

I am trying to create multiple iframes with urls of the same origin in a website and then loop through each iframe to access an element with the same id and currently have the element's innerHTML logged to the console. When I do this individually it works but when I try looping through the iframes I created, I get an error on the console. This for a chrome extension and I am running this through chrome.

Code:

```
var iframe;
  for (var i = 0; i < num_courses; i++) {
    iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.setAttribute("src", links[i].href);
    iframe.id = "i_frame" + i;
    // iframe.height = 0;
    // iframe.width = 0;
    // iframe.style.border = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < num_links; i++) {
    document.getElementById('i_frame' + i).onload = function() {
      var main = document.getElementById('i_frame' + i).contentDocument.getElementById('percentage').innerHTML;
      var percentages = main.match(/(\d|\.)+\%/g);
      console.log(percentages[0]);
    };
  }
```

The error occurs on the line:

```
var main = document.getElementById('i_frame' + i).contentDocument.getElementById('class_avg').innerHTML;"
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentDocument' of null
                    at HTMLIFrameElement.document.getElementById.onload
```

Comment: This is a standard problem of nonscoped `var` variable inside a loop. You need to use `let` or simply replace the second `document.getElementById('i_frame'+i)` with `this`.

Comment: using `this` works, but how can I use an array of values created outside the onload() function, inside the function?

Comment: I figured it out